# Где размещать отрывки кода?

Tags: android, php, html

Всем привет. Сейчас начинаю изучать программирование под Android. Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли какой нибудь онлайн сервис где можно сохранять кусочки кода. Что бы в дальнейшем можно было б заглянуть и посмотреть, какие методы, какие объекты как работают с моим описание. Не хотелось бы создавать свой сервис такой((( СПАСИБО!

Comment: Что мешает просто хранить код с комментариями?

Comment: [Система управления версиями][1]

[Обучалка 1 ][2][Обучалка 2][3]


  [1]: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%E8%F1%F2%E5%EC%E0_%F3%EF%F0%E0%E2%EB%E5%ED%E8%FF_%E2%E5%F0%F1%E8%FF%EC%E8
  [2]: http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/
  [3]: https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/

http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Для сниппетов лучше https://gist.github.com подойдет.

Answer (score 1):

[Вот один](http://eval.in) очень хороший сервис

Comment: До *очень хорошего* недотягивает

(например, статус завершения программы (`exit(CODE);`) я нигде не увидел).

Comment: @avp статус завершения у меня работал, жаль ссылка на код не дожила до этого момента.